# Random intercepts as response variables: Is there a name for this method?

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to find the name of this method (and ultimately a reference).  The approach is as follows:

1) Fit a mixed-effect model with a random intercept

$$
 E(Y_{ij})= \beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\gamma_{0j}
$$

2) Use the estimated random intercepts as the response variables in a new linear regression

$$
 E(\gamma_{0j})= \beta_2+\beta_3z_3
$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question to give equations for both model steps (or at least for the second model step)? You can edit by clicking the "edit" link in the lower left.

Comment: hierarchical model, multi-level model (Bayesian or not). Alternatively, you can view step 1) as a data summarization step, and the real modelling is in step 2).

Comment: I added the equations, I hope that helps convey what I'm doing.

Comment: @qoheleth thanks, I think that's it.  I found some useful info searching for multi-level models.

Comment: I think this is related to what Andrew Gelman calls "the secret Weapon"

Comment: This is exactly how social scientists think about mixed models (or rather the models they call multilevel). See say [Raudenbush and Bryk's book](http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchical-Linear-Models-Applications-Quantitative/dp/076191904X).

Comment: Note that random effects are random variables not parameters. Thus, they are not estimated but rather predicted.

Comment: @qoheleth you should post that as answer. Short and simple does not mean unworthy of a green checkmark.

Comment: @StasK Thank you for the reference, it looks very useful.

Comment: @MichaelMayer Thank you for the clarification.  What are the consequences of that distinction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just re-posting my comments as @ssdecontrol suggested.

**my answer:**

hierarchical model, multi-level model (Bayesian or not). Alternatively, you can view step 1) as a data summarization step, and the real modelling is in step 2).